# Putting a website into Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control

Say I have a website up and running already. And I want to start using Subversion for source control.

- Step 1, create a repository of the entire site -- no problem.
- Step 2, check it out to a development area, code and test -- no problem.
- Step 3, commit changes to the repository -- no problem.
- Step 4, update the live site from the repository -- this is why I'm asking...

It seems to me that I could just go to the website root and do this:

```
svn checkout file:///path/to/repo /path/to/website/root/ --force
```

and it would make the website into a Working Copy of the repository. The `--force` option is there because normally an `svn checkout` doesn't overwrite files already there. Then whenever I need to do Step 4 I can just use `svn update` to change any files which need to be changed.

That seems like an elegant setup and workflow (assuming I handle the security issues caused by a live site also being an `svn` Working Copy). The `update` command will certainly be better than `export`, because it will only change files which need to be changed.

But will there be any problems with the files, permissions etc.? I'm a little nervous to try it.

I tested it on a backup of the site and it put E for 'exists' next to all the files, so I'm not sure it even copied anything across.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of experiment that would be best performed on a test server first.

Comment: Logical. I don't have the luxury of having a test server exactly the same as the first server, but I guess I can get close.

Comment: Using Xen / VMWare / Parallels is a great way to create test servers quickly from existing production configurations (using snapshots).

Answer (score 2):

Making "export" is preferable just because it does not make .svn directories.
If you prefer making "checkout" with "update" (you're right, it will update only something that's changed), don't forget to delete all those .svn.

Those hidden dirs are one of best-known vulnerabilities for hacking websites, because it allows seeing you source files' content.

Comment: "all those .svn" -- don't more recent versions just have one at the root? And I'm assuming I can just hide them, not delete them.

Comment: Sure, you can hide it or use recent version SVN. I just wanted to emphacise that it's the security issue which web developers often face with.

Comment: I have set the .htaccess to return a 404 for .svn directories. My hosting company was returning 403 -- not quite as secure because it tells the bad guys the file is there...